# Why was this question about Eminent Domain data deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I recently answered [this question on Eminent Domain statistics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/34281/are-there-any-statistics-on-eminent-domain/34282#34282) with decent citations. Other discussions in the comments were relevant (and not the "debate club" that often results in these deletions). Why was this question deleted by the Community moderator? It was reasonably asked and answered, and could be used in response to future duplicate questions about Eminent Domain.

Comment: This is strange for an upvoted question with a few answers attached to it. At least we can cast undelete votes (currently two more are required to undelete it).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The user and all their content were deleted because after the user posted this question they went on a trolling spree and posted a series of extremely offensive one-liner questions.

However, this one question has value. I undeleted it.

Comment: This makes way more sense. Many thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

It wasn't deleted by a mod, it says it was deleted by the "Community" user.

That usually means that some automated process did it.  At a quick glance, the question doesn't seem to have a lot of flags or downvotes, so I'm not sure what triggered that automatic process.

Another thing I noticed is that the User's name is greyed out, which means that he doesn't have an account for Politics.SE, which might be related to why the Community user is listed as the deletion user.

Comment: You may get a better answer at Meta.stackexchange.com, since this has more to do with how the SE Site itself works works than it does with anything specific to politics.se

Comment: This is good information, I appreciate it. I've never asked or answered anything on the meta stacks before, so I wasn't quite sure how to approach it – your explanation makes more sense regarding the appropriate forums for moderation vs. content-related meta posts.

Comment: @SamIam The revision history doesn't give the full picture, the [question's timeline](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/34281/timeline) is a bit more helpful - the deletion is a result of the "User 22848 destroyed" event.